# "iOSDeployment Target" vs "Minimum Deployment"

Tags: ios, xcode

What's the difference?

[image]

[image]

What is configured with the two different settings? When do I have do use them? Respectively when do I have to modify them?

Comment: You may have many targets in your project and build for each one separately, you can define the minimum target for each one separately

Comment: @MaziarSaadatfar Thanks. But why does it exist two times, in two different places?

Comment: One of them for generally and another one for specific target, I think.

Comment: @HangarRash The Target Deployment is the default configuration. The Minimum Deployment can overwrite the Target Deployment, concerning a specific target. Have I get it right?

Comment: @a.hess Yes, that is correct, just as stated in the duplicate I linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both set `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`, but in different parts of the project file.

Each entry is in `isa = XCBuildConfiguration`, which is in `isa = XCConfigurationList` (usually two configs, because of Debug & Release)

Each list will live in either `isa = PBXProject` or `isa = PBXNativeTarget`.

From the perspective of an Xcode user, I'm not sure that the project-level value is useful anymore, when I added targets to my test project, they all ignored the project value (I was using "15.6"), and went right to "17.0"

Comment: Developers shouldn't set these directly in Xcode anyway. They should be set in a xcconfig file.

Comment: Agreed, wasn't suggesting hacking the file, but wanted to explain exactly where its being set. (Also some devs like me do read thru the diffs when we checkin). Looking at some of my older Xcode notes, I think the default-value thing used to work, but in Xcode 15 RC, at least for some targets, it just says: "you should use 17.0, I don't care what your project thinks."